# Problema para encontrar o IP

Tags: php

```
function getRealIP() {

    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];

    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];

    return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

echo getRealIP();

echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Qual o problema desse código?
Porquê o resultado dele só fica assim `::1`, tentei vários vezes e só dá esse resultado.

Comment: Se você estiver rodando o script em rede local, o resultado será esse mesmo. Esse é o IP da interface lo (loopback). Tente usar em produção ou em uma plataforma de teste como o phptester.net

Answer (score 3):

Não tem erro, ele ta retornando o valor do IPv6:

"O nome localhost normalmente resolve para o IPv4 loopback endereço 127.0.0.1 , e para o IPv6 endereço de auto-retorno :: 1."

Tente configurar o Apache corretamente.